# Catching resource filename errors at compile time

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I'm doing my first iOS App with Monotouch and I'm loading quite a lot of images from my resources directory. Every now and then I get a typo in a filename and the app will then crash on me spewing out some unintelligible error message. (I'll try adding deciphering stack traces to my skill set any day now ...)

I was thinking that there must be a smarter way to handle this. For example one could have a utility script that goes through the resources directory and constructs a list of global constants based on its contents. Each file in the resources gets an entry.

So that MyResources/Icons/HomeIcon.png will be represented by the constant `MyResources.Icons.HomeIcon_png`. Then one could have something like Inotify (don't know what that would be on Mac) watch the resources directory and regenerate the constants file on every change.

This would of course also give nice autocompletion for resources.

Maybe there's already something like this is already in Monodevelop or online somewhere? Otherwise how would I go about setting it up?

Or maybe there's some other smart way of mitigating the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I spent four precious hours to cook up this little python script that sort of solves my problem. For now it's the best solution to my problem.

http://github.com/oivvio/Monodevelop-Resources-as-Constants

Answer (score 1):

Your primary problem is typos in resource names are not caught early, and only cause crashes when the app is actually ran.

Your proposed solution of a list of global constants generated based on the available resources is kind of neat, but as far as I know this does not exist yet.

In the mean time, you could manually construct this list of global constants, and create a unit test that verifies all the elements in this list are valid resources (by looping through them automatically, of course - adding a resource to the list should not require a change to the test).

This way you can catch typos earlier (when you run the unit test rather than when you run the app), which is your primary concern. Additionally, if you ever find/write the script you envision, your application code is already prepared.

Answer (score 0):

I filed an enhancement bug on Xamarin bugzilla for you: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3760